# Why does Google Play show the currency AED for Egypt?

Tags: google-play-store

I used HMA to change my location but the google play didn’t show the corresponding currency. For example, it showed AED for Egypt, CZK for Myanmar, UAH for Congo. Which location should I move to get the currency of Egypt?

For more information, when I haven't logged to google account, google play store shows Egypt currency. However when I create new account, add a Egypt Billing address, it show AED currency.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bizarre as it may seem, this is likely happening because you are signed in with your Google Account while accessing the Play Store. Sign out of your Google Account, clear all caches and history and then visit the Play Store and you should see that the currency will now be changed to the currency in Egypt.

Comment: For more information, when I haven't logged to google account, google play store shows Egypt currency. However when I create new account, add a Egypt Billing address, it show AED currency.
Of course I would like to change to Egypt currency to buy app with better price

Comment: When adding a Egypt billing address, did you also add a credit card which was issued in Egypt?

Comment: No. I used a card from Vietnam. I wouldn't be surprised if it showed Vietnam currency but actually showed aed. However I accepted yout answer. The reason why Google Play shows aed for account in egypt may be out of this question's scope

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to **clear cache** and **cookies** when changing IP (remember to clear **flash cache** too). Alternatively you can use **incognito mode**.

Furthermore I have strong feeling this has to do with VPN servers being used by HMA during the connection. On [HMA support page](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007313287-No-vpn-ip-change-from-google?mobile_site=true), they actually have acknowledged that they're testing new servers and often times these may not reflect true location (*I recall experiencing these same issue with Psiphon VPN showing a mismatch between selected and apparent locations*):

> During the recent upgrades of our network we have replaced certain
>   servers with the new, better ones, allowing greater speed and a more
>   stable connection. We are aware that when connected to these new
>   servers, our customers are getting Google results in Czech. As these
>   servers are brand new, it may take some time for the Google to reflect
>   their true location.

Additionally I suspect, the VPN configuration somehow gets buggy especially when congested with traffic such that it "auto-picks" servers close to your actual location, probably because there is faster speed and lower latency than servers that are much further from real location.

You may therefore wish to check if the IP location of the chosen connection is correct on [geoip.hidemyass.com](http://geoip.hidemyass.com) or similar IP checkers (such as maxmind.com or whoer.net).